# RemoveChild Not Working AS3 Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having a problem here because I'm trying to remove any instances of the rectangle while the Congratulations message is on the the screen. Code is a bit messy but I've been messing around with it a lot to try to figure this out. If I change the `addChild` to `stage.addChild` this gives me errors due to the shooting and removing of them in the `shootMob` function. I've also referred to it as `rectangle.parent.removeChild(rectange)` but this also won't work. Any ideas?

```
function spawnMob1():void  
{  
    if (gameLevel==1)
    {
    var rectangle:MovieClip = new ball_mc();
        rectangle.x = randomRange(583);
    rectangle.y = randomRange(100);
    addChild(rectangle);

    var mobMoveX:Tween = new Tween(rectangle, "x", None.easeOut, rectangle.x, character_mc.x, 6, true);
    var mobMoveY:Tween = new Tween(rectangle, "y", None.easeOut, rectangle.y, character_mc.y, 6, true);


    rectangle.visible = true;

    rectangle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootMob);
    function shootMob(e:MouseEvent): void
    {
        if (contains(rectangle)) 
        {
            removeChild(rectangle);
            score_txt.text = String(score);
        }
        score+=20;
        trace("Score:" + score);
    }

        if (score>=60)
        {
            trace("Congratulations!");
            congratulations1_mc.visible = true;

            trace("GameLevel:" + gameLevel);


            removeChild(rectangle);
//          rectangle.visible = false;

            gameLevel = 0;

        }


    character_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, charHit);

    function charHit(event:Event): void
    {
        if (rectangle.hitTestObject(character_mc))
        {
            if (contains(rectangle)) 
                        {
                       removeChild(rectangle);
            if (health>0)
            {
                health-=5;
                health_txt.text = String(health);
                trace("boop");
                trace("Health:" + health);
            } else if (health<=0) {
                    trace("You have died");
                    death_mc.visible = true;
                    gameLevel=0;

            }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Could be a scope issue, the way you're using local functions; unless there's a typo in what you've cited.  I wouldn't reference the `rectangle` instance from the mouse event handler - you're relying on a stale reference from your function inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

You've misplaced a `}`. `shootMob` should include the `(score>=60)` block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I moved it into the Spawnmob block but it's still remaining on the stage. The mobs stop spawning because of the change in gameLevel value and everything, I just cannot remove the existing ones (moving towards the target) to leave the stage. I wasn't happy about putting the functions inside another function, but doing anything else cause referring to "rectangle" to cause null object errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
Writing one function inside another function is a bad coding style. What about this instead:

    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

 var score_txt:TextField = new TextField(50,50,0xFFFFF);
    var score:Number;
    var gameLevel:int = 1;

 var rectangle:MovieClip;

    //function spawnMob1():void  
    //{  
        if (gameLevel==1)
        {
   rectangle = new ball_mc()

    rectangle.x =  randomRange(583);
    rectangle.y =  randomRange(100);
    addChild(rectangle);

    var mobMoveX:Tween = new Tween(rectangle,"x",None.easeOut,rectangle.x,character_mc.x,6,true);
    var mobMoveY:Tween = new Tween(rectangle,"y",None.easeOut,rectangle.y,character_mc.y,6,true);
     rectangle.visible = true;

    rectangle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootMob);

}

    function shootMob(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (contains(rectangle))
        {
            removeChild(rectangle);
            score_txt.text = String(score);
        }
        score +=  20;
        trace("Score:" + score);

    if (score>=60)
    {
        trace("Congratulations!");
        congratulations1_mc.visible = true;
        trace("GameLevel:" + gameLevel);
        if(rectangle || congratulations1_mc.visible == true)
        removeChild(rectangle);
        gameLevel = 0;
    }
}

    character_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, charHit);

    function charHit(event:Event):void
    {
        if (rectangle.hitTestObject(character_mc))
        {
            if (contains(rectangle))
            {
                removeChild(rectangle);
                if (health>0)
                {
                    health -=  5;
                    health_txt.text = String(health);
                    trace("boop");
                    trace("Health:" + health);
                }
                else if (health<=0)
                {
                    trace("You have died");
                    death_mc.visible = true;
                    gameLevel = 0;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried this and everything so far is working fine however, obviously this is only adding one child. How would you suggest going about adding more spawns? Will I put it back in the existing gameLevel==1 if statement?

Comment: No i just commented due to regularise your code. if it requires u can add that condition.i can't understand what u are checking on that gameLevel ==1 condition. what's the need of that. or declare that rectangle variable outside that function as you  can get everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to ask was that if I reintroduce the setInterval method (or even a timer), the creation of the mobs would have to be inside a function. If this is inside a function, the other calls to "rectangle" would have to be within this function due to previous errors I can't access "rectangle" without being inside the function that creates them.

Comment: Cant't you declare ur rectangle variable outside the function globallly.

Comment: Tried that that other day, doing so seems to keep redrawing the movieClip instance (using your code) back at x:100 y:10 and it never makes a full path to the character_mc. I'm assuming this is because the rectangle variable is being overwritten at the frame rate?

Comment: Just tried it out there. This is creating multiple spawns but trying to carry out charHit function is giving me null object reference errors at every spawn even though the rectangle variable is being created outside the spawnMob function. Code is here, I've just moved around some variables but I've been looking at this for so long there could be a really obvious problem that I could be missing. http://pastebin.com/GGsjxpdR